# Remove spaces at the start of each line in a multiline string variable

Tags: php, html, regex

I have tried to remove spaces from paragraphs, but it fails.

I have input like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et nisl
>   nulla. Aenean interdum eget augue vehicula commodo. Etiam condimentum.
>
> --Nunc lacinia dui eget volutpat porta. Morbi eu magna ornare,
>   facilisis risus eget, varius sem. Proin hendrerit lacus condimentum.
>
> --Duis eget vehicula orci. Curabitur laoreet velit sit amet ligula
>   congue, eget consectetur risus ultricies. Curabitur dictum felis at.

I have spaces where I mention "--", I need to remove the spaces from there.

I have tried these:

```
str_replace(' ', '', $string)
preg_replace('/\s+/',
preg_replace('!(\<br ?/?\>)([ ]|\t)+!i', '<br />', $str);
string.replaceAll("<br />\\p{Space}+", "<br />");
```

Nothing works if I change `\t` to `\s`. It will remove spaces but it will also remove spaces from between words.

Comment: Do you want to remove spaces or add a space after `--` ?

Comment: Does it mean you have `<br/>` as a linebreak? Try [`preg_replace('~((?:<br\s*/?>\R?){2})\h+~', '$1', $str)`](https://regex101.com/r/dI9qG9/1)

Comment: @PankajPawar have you tried my alternative?

Comment: That three paragraph is in one variable(one string).

Comment: where i have mention "--" there is space and i want to remove that. and three paragraph is in one variable(one string).

Comment: Clarified title: reflect that spaces of each line in a variable should be removed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

None of the currently posted answers are presenting any elegance or directness.

My regular expression contains 3 characters and a pattern modifier. `/^ +/m`

- `m` at the end dictates that any `^` found in the pattern will represent the start of every newline (instead of the start of the string like it normally does).
- I am using a literal blank character though some developers prefer to use `\s` for readability and to cover a range of whitespace characters that might be encountered.
- `+` means one or more of the previous character/expression.  I could have used a finite quantifier `/^ {2}/m` but chose pattern brevity and flexibility in this case.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FqNXa))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et nisl nulla. Aenean interdum eget augue vehicula commodo. Etiam condimentum.

  Nunc lacinia dui eget volutpat porta. Morbi eu magna ornare, facilisis risus eget, varius sem. Proin hendrerit lacus condimentum.

  Duis eget vehicula orci. Curabitur laoreet velit sit amet ligula congue, eget consectetur risus ultricies. Curabitur dictum felis at.
TEXT;

echo preg_replace('/^ +/m', '', $text);
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et nisl nulla. Aenean interdum eget augue vehicula commodo. Etiam condimentum.

Nunc lacinia dui eget volutpat porta. Morbi eu magna ornare, facilisis risus eget, varius sem. Proin hendrerit lacus condimentum.

Duis eget vehicula orci. Curabitur laoreet velit sit amet ligula congue, eget consectetur risus ultricies. Curabitur dictum felis at.
```

Comment: Beautifully simple. Thanks for breaking down the logic behind it!

Comment: @Inc best to var_dump your string and try to figure out if it is _actually_ a single-byte literal space or if it is some other whitespace character. Might it be a unicode/multibyte character? You'll have to let me know.

Comment: `/^ */m` would do unnecessary work -- it would also replace emtpy strings with empty strings.

Comment: You are right ... for some reason when I initially was using what you had, every line had a pre-space on it. However now, after having gone back to the finalized cleaner code and just putting in `/^\s*/m` (to clear tabs too), it all just works. So, ignore my initial comment (deleted it). Sorry. And yes this is the most elegant/nice solution!

Comment: I'll recommend that you use `/^\s+/m`.  As I said earlier, `*` will do needless work by replacing a zero-width string with a zero-width string.  Use `+` for "one or more".

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "REPlACE THIS WITH YOUR TEXT STRING";
// split the string by the newline character, no limit, without empty
$_arr = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/",$str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$arr=[];
foreach($_arr as $line){
    // trim these line
    array_push($arr,trim($line));
}

var_dump($arr);
```

I have tested, works.

Answer (score 1):

```
join("\n", array_map('trim', preg_split('/\R/', $string)));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//separates the paragraph into 3 strings, divided by '--'
  list($string1, $string2, $string3) = explode('--',$string);

//trim() takes out the spaces before and after each string
  $string1 = trim($string1);
  $string2 = trim($string2);
  $string3 = trim($string3);

  echo $string1." ".$string2." ".$string3;
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: There are no `--` in the original text: *i have spaces where i mention "--" i need to remove this spaces from there.*

Comment: That three paragraph is in one variable(one string).

Comment: @PankajPawar alright.. replace `explode('--',$string)` with `explode(PHP_EOL,$string)`, and if that doesn't work, try: `explode('\n',$string)` . Do one of those work?

Answer (score -1):

you can use from trim like this:

```
ltrim($string, ' ');
```

this code will remove first space from $string, also there are rtrim, trim functions.